# What is the point of cross-references in `incollection`?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

I was having trouble with my references for a chapter of a book that has many authors. My reference was being (in APA-like style) rendered like this:

> Chapter Author (2017). Chapter title. chapter 2. Book Publisher.

What's missing there is the refenrece to the book.

Eventually I found that I need the book title in the chapter entry:

```
\begin{filecontents}{hh.bib}
@incollection{achapter,
Title     = {Chapter Title},
Author    = {{Chapter Author}},
Booktitle = {{Wrong Book Title}},
Chapter   = {2},
Year      = {2077},
Crossref  = {abook},
}

@book{abook,
Title     = {Book Title},
Editor    = {{Book Editor}},
Author    = {{Book Author}},
Publisher = {{Book Publisher}},
Year      = {2017},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
Hey \citep{achapter}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{hh}
\end{document}
```

Which leaves me puzzled. I assumed cross-references were tools to make my life easier—less risk of inserting conflicting information, for instance, like I did in the example with two different book titles. What is the point of `Crossref` if my `@incollection` entry requires `Booktitle` and `Year`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us say you have some of the books of Prof. Knuth "The Art of Computer 
Programming". For all books you can use the bib entry

```
@BOOK{TAOCP,
  author    = {Donald E. Knuth},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  title     = {The Art of Computer Programming},
  series    = {7 B\"ande},
  year      = 1968,
}
```

To be able to cite book 2 you write the bib entry

```
@BOOK{TAOCP2,
  crossref = {TAOCP},
  title    = {Seminumerical Algorithms},
  volume   = 2,
  series   = {The Art of Computer Programming},
  edition  = {Second},
  year     = 1981,
}
```

with the cross reference to `TOACP`.  This entry misses an author and the 
publisher to be valid for `bibtex`. Via `crossref` field BiBTeX is able to 
fetch the missing informations ...

In your case you need to write the following entry for your `incollection` 
to omit warnings about empty fields:

```
@incollection{achapter,
  Crossref  = {acollection},
  Author    = {{Chapter Author}},
  Title     = {Chapter Title},
  Editor    = {{Chapter Editor}},
  booktitle = {{Collection Title incollection}},
  Chapter   = {2},
  Year      = {2077},
}
```

With the cross reference you can get the missing publisher from entry 
`acollection`. You need to write field `booktitle` because it does not exist in the cross reference with the same name. Because your style `apalike` does not know `collection` you need to use `book`:

```
@book{acollection,
  Title     = {Collection Title},
  Editor    = {{Collection Editor}},
  Year      = {2017},
  Publisher = {{Collection Publisher}},
}
```

With the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{TAOCP2,
  crossref = {TAOCP},
  title    = {Seminumerical Algorithms},
  volume   = 2,
  series   = {The Art of Computer Programming},
  edition  = {Second},
  year     = 1981,
}
@BOOK{TAOCP,
  author    = {Donald E. Knuth},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  title     = {The Art of Computer Programming},
  series    = {7 B\"ande},
  year      = 1968,
}
@incollection{achapter,
  Crossref  = {acollection},
  Author    = {{Chapter Author}},
  Title     = {Chapter Title},
  Editor    = {{Chapter Editor}},
  booktitle = {{Collection Title incollection}},
  Chapter   = {2},
  Year      = {2077},
}
@book{acollection,
  Title     = {Collection Title},
  Editor    = {{Collection Editor}},
  Year      = {2017},
  Publisher = {{Collection Publisher}},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

Citing \citep{TAOCP2} please see the author and publisher comes 
from entry \texttt{TAOCP}! 

Citing \citep{achapter} please see the publisher comes from entry 
\texttt{acollection}.

\bibliographystyle{apalike} % apalike plain
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

you get the result (see the red markings):

[image: resulting pdf]